# Unable to substitute value of variable in Thymeleaf's th:src tag

Tags: thymeleaf

I was using one basic image tag in velocity template. Now I am converting that tag to thymeleaf templates.

```
<img src="@domain.org.protocol@://${notiData.template}.@domain.org.template@/images/email/mail-icon.png">
```

Unable to substitue ${notiData.template} value which is coming in context to my thymeleaf template.

Comment: Your code shows src= not th:src=. Is this the substituted form? Did you use as in the documentation th:src=@{<something>}? Your question have little information about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... as stated in the comment, you have to prefix attribute with Thymeleaf expressions in them with `th:`.

As for your actual expression, you'll need to understand [standard Thymeleaf expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax)...

```
<img th:src="${'@domain.org.protocol@://' + notiData.template + '.@domain.org.template@/images/email/mail-icon.png'}">
```